# netbeans showing errors in the end of css code but i cant find where is the error

Tags: css, netbeans

My Netbeans is showing errors in the end of CSS code, but I cannot find where is the error, may be there will be a missing ending bracket somewhere in the code but how can I find the error line number.

There are 6000 lines in my code, This may be very simple but I cannot find a valid answer for that.
[image]

Comment: Could you paste the code here? What does the lightbulb say when you hover it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be an issue of a missing semicolon. If you have faced this error recently then you can look into recent changes you made in css.
Or you can trace your error from this site
http://csslint.net/

Comment: Thank you, I got it, this site showed me the error line number, a closing bracket was missing at 2068